# Extract all Parameters with RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following SQL sample statement in a string variable

```
INSERT INTO T_Application
(
    ApplicationGroupId,
    Name,
    Component,
    SubComponent,
    Description
)
VALUES
(
    @ApplicationGroupId,
    @Name,
    @Component,
    @SubComponent,
    @Description
)

SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

What I want is to have all Parameter names (Id, ApplicationGroupId, Name, Component, SubComponent, Description) in a `List<string>`.
How can I write the RegEx to extract all Parameters Names? The RegEx should also work if the Parameters are in one line, spaces between `,` etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Regex.Matches(sql, @"\@\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList ();
```

Resulting List:

```
@ApplicationGroupId
@Name
@Component
@SubComponent
@Description
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex:

```
\({0,1}\s*(\w*)\,
```

You can then get the matches using flags

Comment: This won't include `@Id` in the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regular expression :

```
insert into[\s\S]+?\((?<parameter_names>([\s\S]+?))\)
```

You will get all the parameters in group named '**parameter_names**'.

Comment: This won't include `@Id` in the matches.

Comment: @Justin, ur right... i guess i have to change my regex. thanks for comment.